# Visual Studio 2010 and C# Syntax about Nullable<T>?

Tags: c#, wsdl, console-application

Using: Visual Studio 2010
Created: Console Application in C#
Accessing: a Java created WSDL file

I am trying to figure out the syntax for `productType?[] LicenseTypes` as shown in the image. 
I was trying the following:

`LicenseTypes: productType.Any);`

This line failed saying it cannot conver a ' to a []?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Image of Issue:
http://img256.imageshack.us/img256/9681/52654686.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`productType?[]` is an array of nullable `productType`s while `productType.Any` presumably is a scalar `productType`. To make an array out of it, you would use something like `new productType?[] { productType.Any }`.